# How to deploy a Web App using Visual Studio to Azure App Service Environment?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to deploy a Web application to an **App Service Environment** but when I try to publish the web app I get this error.

**"Web deployment task failed. ( Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxx-xx-xx-xx.scm.xx.xx.com"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.)"**

Although the publishing profile of the web app gets created successfully and the basic web app template starts appearing in the Resource Group containing the App Service Environment.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use ILB ASE? You probably need to set up certificate and DNS for your ASE subdomain. Check this out https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer/ regarding how to configure your ASE

Edit: if you use ILB ASE, it means that anything outside of the ASE VNET cannot reach the apps. You can either spin up a VM inside that ASE VNET and deploy from there, or you need a VPN connection to that VNET.

I know it is somewhat confusing when you do ILB ASE, so I wrote a post about it, [check it out](https://medium.com/@ericjwhuang/hosting-apis-in-azure-5bd5fa6f3375#89df) if you are interested in it

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot deploy a VM in an ASE VNet. An ASE is the only resource allowed in the VNet, this means nothing but the ASE can be in the VNet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-an-app-service-environment#overview

Comment: @Soeren that is true for the Subnet in which the ASE is deployed, not the entire VNET.  Set up a separate Subnet within the VNET and deploy a VM into it.